# React-native-sound-player not playing audio. No errors in debugger

Tags: react-native, react-native-track-player

I was using react-native-sound-player with no issues but its now unsupported and it does not work with android so I converted to react-native-track-player but I'm unable to get it to play audio. The flow I have is the tracks to stream are fetched from my firestore database then its parsed since its an m3u file. I have a button that calls handleTrackPress to check if the stream is playing or not. If it is it stops the stream and if its not it will start playing the stream. I can see the app connecting to my streaming server but I have no audio. Here is what I got. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Image, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';
import { Parser } from 'm3u8-parser';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import { AuthContext } from '../navigation/AuthProvider';

const Scanner = () => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [tracks, setTracks] = useState([]);
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(() => {
      // Player is initialized, continue with other operations
      fetchTracks();
    });

    return () => {
      // Clean up resources when the component is unmounted
      TrackPlayer.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  const fetchTracks = async () => {
    try {
      // Get the agency name for the current user from Firestore
      const userSnapshot = await firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();
      const agency = userSnapshot.data().agency;

      console.log('Agency:', agency);

      // Fetch the data from the Firestore collection
      const snapshot = await firestore().collection(`${agency} Scanner`).get();
      console.log('Full data string:', snapshot);
      const tracksData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        Feedname: doc.data().Feedname,
        Feedurl: doc.data().Feedurl,
        Frequencies: doc.data().Frequencies,
        disabled: doc.data().disabled,
      }));
      console.log('Retrieved Tracks:', tracksData);

      setTracks(tracksData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleTrackPress = async (item) => {
    try {
      if (isPlaying) {
        await TrackPlayer.stop();
        setIsPlaying(false);
      } else {
        // Parse the m3u file using m3u8-parser
        const response = await fetch(item.Feedurl);
        const text = await response.text();
  
        const parser = new Parser();
        parser.push(text);
        parser.end();
  
        const manifest = parser.manifest;
        console.log('Manifest:', manifest); // Add this line to log the manifest object
  
        if (manifest && manifest.segments && manifest.segments.length > 0) {
          const url = manifest.segments[0].uri;
          console.log('Segment URL:', url); // Add this line to log the segment URL
  
          await TrackPlayer.add({
            id: item.id,
            url: url,
            title: item.Feedname,
          });
          await TrackPlayer.play(); // Move this line here
          setIsPlaying(true);
        } else {
          console.log('Invalid m3u file or no segments found');
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Cannot play the sound file', error.message, error.stack);
    }
  };
  

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const dotColor = item.disabled ? 'red' : 'green';

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleTrackPress(item)}>
        <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
          <View style={[styles.dot, { backgroundColor: dotColor }]} />
          <View style={styles.textContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{item.Feedname}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemSubtitle}>{item.Frequencies}</Text>
          </View>
          {isPlaying ? (
            <Image source={require('../assets/pause_icon.png')} style={styles.pauseIcon} />
          ) : (
            <Image source={require('../assets/play_icon.png')} style={styles.playIcon} />
          )}
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.pageTitle}>Your Scanner Feeds</Text>
      <FlatList data={tracks} renderItem={renderItem} keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} />
    </View>
  );
};

//styles

export default Scanner;
```

my service.js file for RNtrackplayer:

```
import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';


module.exports = async function () {

  try {
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-play', () => {
      TrackPlayer.play()
    })

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-pause', () => {
      TrackPlayer.pause()
    });

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-next', () => {
      TrackPlayer.skipToNext()
    });

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-previous', () => {
      TrackPlayer.skipToPrevious()
    });

    TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-stop', () => {
      TrackPlayer.destroy()
    });
  } catch (error) { }

};
```